# Preventing windows 10 from being installed

Tags: windows-7

I have windows 7 and do NOT want windows 10. I have the windows logo in my tray and have removed it twice. It always comes back. 
   What I want is a SIMPLE way to prevent windows 10 from being installed on my computer. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The german Webseite [heise provided a small script](ftp://ftp.heise.de/pub/ct/listings/1516-159.zip) hat you can run.

Extract the `1516-159.zip` and run the `NoGWX.cmd` as [admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token). It removes the Update KB3035583 and sets the value `DisableOSUpgrade` to `1` to prevent an Upgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: Alternative utility in English found [via this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/228551/how-to-stop-windows-7-or-8-from-downloading-windows-10-automatically/): [GWX control panel](http://ultimateoutsider.com/downloads/) also has this function under "Are Windows Updates OS upgrades enabled?"

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to get ride of the tray icon, open Task Manager and end process for GWX.exe. Then, go to C:/Windows/System32 and right-click on the GWX folder and go to Properties > Security > Advanced. Here, change the owner from TrustedInstaller to Everyone or Users or Administrators. Click OK to close the Windows and you can now delete the entire GWX folder.

Windows 10 shows up as an optional update, so even with automatic updates enabled, it shouldn't install without your permission.

Answer (score -2):

The update that installs this Windows 10 ad is called [KB3035583](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583)

Go to Control Panel, and then Windows Update. Check in the bottom left corner for a link to Installed Updates. Look down the list for a Windows patch named KB3035583, which can be uninstalled by right-clicking on the entry and selecting Uninstall. Windows being Windows, you will then be prompted to completely restart your computer. But once you do, the Windows 10 icon should be absent from your Taskbar's notification area.

You will need to turn off Automatic Updates to not have it installed again on its own.